# Hibernate Save Java Collection in a single shot

Tags: java, hibernate

We use Hibernate 5 and we need to persist upto 1 million of records every day, right now code we use is

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            for (CustomObject customObject : CustomObjectList)
            {
                session.save(customObject);
            }
            log.info("Saved all entities in Hibernate Session");
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            log.error("HibernateException  :{}", e.getMessage(), e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            session.clear();
        }
        finally
        {
           HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
        }
```

Here CustomObject is my Table Entity, so my CustomObjectList contains 1 million records and persisting into Database using default bulk insert property

Can we persist all list values in a single shot instead of iterating , What is the best way to improve performance?

Is Something like `session.save(customObjectList)` possible?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch-insert